# Uncaught TypeError: ReactIs.isMemo is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react.js

I upgraded to React version 16.0.1 and it throws the error "Uncaught TypeError: ReactIs.isMemo is not a function". I also upgraded react-redux v6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Change the package.json:

```
"react": "16.12.0", (or higher)
"react-is": "^16.13.1",
```

Then run:

```
npm install react@16.12.0
npm install react-is@latest
npm install
```